# problem with forEach and addEventListenner

Tags: javascript, html

hello I have the following code, the problem is that when iterating with forEach it affects all the elements of the nodeList that are 3 how could I do to affect it only generates the call to the eventListener?? I need that when I mouse over one of the projects it affects only this one and not the rest

```
const $projects = document.querySelectorAll(".projects__grid__element")

$projects.forEach( (project,index) => {
    
    addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
        
        // const $projectDescription= project.querySelector(project[index]);
        // $projectDescription.style.display= "flex"
    });
    addEventListener('mouseout', (event) => {
        // const $projectDescription= project.querySelector(".projects__grid__element__description");
        // $projectDescription.style.display = "none"
    });
})
```

I need that when I mouse over one of the projects it affects only this one and not the rest

Comment: Make use of `event.target` inside the listener to get a reference to the element that triggered the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `addEventListener`, so the event listener is attached with `window`. But as you want the event listener to be attached on each project instead, so you should use `project.addEventListener`.
like this:

```
const $projects = document.querySelectorAll(".projects__grid__element")

$projects.forEach( (project,index) => {
    
    project.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
        
        // const $projectDescription= project.querySelector(project[index]);
        // $projectDescription.style.display= "flex"
    });
    project.addEventListener('mouseout', (event) => {
        // const $projectDescription= project.querySelector(".projects__grid__element__description");
        // $projectDescription.style.display = "none"
    });
})
```

And its better if you attach the event listener to the parent of `$projects` element, so when you later remove or add new project elements into it the event listener will work, no extra work needed.